# O que é Data Warehouse e quais suas vantagens e desvantagens?

Tags: banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

O que é Data Warehouse e quais as vantagens e desvantagens da utilização disto.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

É um conceito abstrato que indica que você está consolidando dados de diversas fontes e aplicações de uma organização em um único "local" facilitando suas consultas e eventualmente manipulação.

Normalmente isso é feito através de um banco de dados e depois de alimentado com dados de fontes externas a ele e estes se tornam independentes das fontes.

O mais comum é usar ferramentas de [OLAP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP) para trabalhar com estes dados, em oposição ao [OLTP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) que é usado em bancos de dados ditos operacionais da organização. Em geral em DW os dados são usados de forma mais analítica, para ajuda em tomada de decisão.

No mundo ideal eles não deveriam ser necessários e todas as fontes deveriam fazer parte do banco de dados principal e seu acesso deveria ser fácil para usá-los como for melhor. Na prática isto raramente é possível em grandes organizações.

É importante ressaltar que as fontes de dados não são necessariamente outros bancos de dados, embora eles sejam a principal fonte de dados para DW.

O assunto é extenso e acho que cabem respostas que se complementem aqui.

## Vantagens

- Integra fontes de dados diversificadas em um só local.
- Os dados são limpos de coisas que só interessam ao mecanismo de operação do banco de dados e da aplicação que o gerencia.
- Ele é um grande indexador de dados.
- É fácil acessar todos dados de formas bem diferentes e complexas de forma simples, integrada e rápida agilizando a tomada de decisão.
- Costuma ser fácil acessar dados históricos.
- Os dados são padronizados e *canonicalizados*.
- O compartilhamento dos dados é facilitado, principalmente através de [data marts](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart), cada um acessa como melhor lhe convém, em teoria.
- O controle de acesso e permissões aos dados é facilitado.
- Em tese reduz a necessidade de intervenção do pessoal de TI nas esferas gerenciais.
- Pode fornecer informações relevantes e difíceis de obter, ajudando prever o que acontecerá.
- Ajuda achar defeitos na organização geral dos dados da organização e ajuda manter consistência já que os dados precisam vir em melhor forma e ser mais compatível com os demais.
- Não afeta os sistemas operacionais (em certo sentido).

## Desvantagens

- Não é fácil captar e transformar os dados de fontes diversas em algo útil para o DW. Costuma-se dizer que o trabalhoso do DW é a transformação que pode reduzir a relação de custo e benefício. É extremamente complicado compatibilizar todos os dados.
- Apesar de controlar o acesso no DW pode haver problemas de segurança e privacidade pelo fato do dado sair da sua fonte que pode ter políticas diferentes.
- A implementação e a manutenção para manter em conformidade com todos os sistemas existentes que estão em constante mutação e novos sistemas não é simples e é caro.
- Ferramentas e infraestrutura extras costumam ser necessárias, nem sempre compensando o custo de aquisição, treinamento e operação, muitas vezes elas concorrem com os sistemas operacionais que são mais importantes para o dia a dia.
- A informação pode ficar obsoleta rapidamente.
- Trabalha bem com alguns cenários mas é um estorvo para outros.
- Muitas vezes ele é complexo demais e é comum as expectativas de uso e resultados esperados serem acima da realidade, expondo uma possível falha na opção de uso.
- É comum gerar conflitos dentro das organizações por causa do seu uso.
- Não é fácil estabelecer e manter regras claras para todas as fases de operação de um DW.
- Não é uma ferramenta mágica que resolve algum problema da organização. Pode-se abusar da informação fornecida ou usá-la de forma inadequada. Dados por si só não dizem tudo.
- É difícil prever todos os problemas que ele trará para a organização.
- É comum dar mais importância do que ele de fato tem e as pessoas começarem trabalhar para ele ao invés de trabalharem com ele.
- Dados poucos estruturados continuam difíceis de trabalhar em DW.

Evidentemente que é possível prevenir que os problemas aconteçam mas não é tarefa fácil e garantida.

Isto é um resumo porque dá para listar dezenas de vantagens e desvantagens. Algumas são variações do que foi dito. Seria interessante um estudo bem feito que mostrasse isto de forma "oficial" e que fosse pensado para evitar redundâncias nos itens sem esquecer de nada.

Não tenho experiência com grandes empresas mas em pequenas e médias (que representam 99% das empresas do mundo, 99,9% se considerar as micro) não costuma dar certo. Em geral é mais fácil organizar uma aplicação corretamente para que o DW não seja necessário, funciona melhor, atende melhor as necessidade e sai mais barato. Muitas vezes a adoção de DW é a confissão de que os sistemas estão em um caos. O que seria a regra em grandes empresas, principalmente heterogêneas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito boa resposta, era exatamente o que eu procurava. Obrigado.