# O que faz um JOIN ser ruim em banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, desempenho, modelagem, join

Onde trabalho atualmente eu tive que fazer algumas consultas no banco de dados para gerar um relatório ou tirar e-mails de alunos que não fizeram rematrículas em outros cursos.

Entretanto, me deram a ideia de fazer esses relatórios em uma página ASP com tabelas utilizando vários `SELECTs` ao invés de uma *query* só utilizando o `JOIN`. E pior que os resultados (pelo menos em quantidade de linhas encontradas) tinham muitas diferenças entre utilizar o `JOIN` ou vários `SELECTS`.

Me disseram que se fizer da maneira de criar uma página ASP e utilizando vários `SELECTs` dava para "colocar a mão no fogo" que aquele resultado era consistente. Do contrário a usar uma só *query* com 3 até 4 `JOINS`.

Detalhe: Aqui onde eu trabalho eles não colocam, durante a criação das tabelas, o uso de *foreign keys*. Colocam apenas uma coluna com o nome, por exemplo, `cod_aluno` mas sem usar o *foreign key* que ligue esta coluna diretamente com a tabela `Alunos`.

Utilizar `JOINs` em casos de 3 ou 4 tabelas seria ruim? O que pode levar a trazer resultados inconsistentes? O que, por via de experiência, recomendariam fazer para que eu consiga gerar ou realizar operações de consulta sem ter que dividir em várias *querys*.

Comment: Geralmente é o programador.

Comment: Ouvir dos colegas que consultas seguidas sem JOIN são mais consistentes do que uma única consulta com JOIN é um primeiro sinal de que você está trabalhando com pessoas que não deveriam estar programando.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O comentário jocoso do Linq (Jéf Bueno ou seja lá que nome ele usa agora) é verdade. Uma parte do problema é realizar o `JOIN` onde não precisa. Ele é um mecanismo automático que pode buscar coisas que você não precisa.

Mas o motivo que normalmente as pessoas falam sobre ele ser problemático é que ele tem que buscar informações em lugares diferentes. Ter que construir uma informação é muito pior que ter ela pronta ali para consumo direto.

## Normalização

Ninguém usa `JOIN` porque quer, ou pelo menos deveria ser assim. Se ele é necessário não tem grande problema. Ele é necessário em bancos [normalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Não normalizar pode trazer problemas, pode funcionar bem em atividades típicas [OLAP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54007/101), mas não em OLTP. A [*desnormalização* correta evita o `JOIN`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101). Mas e daí?

Em geral construir a partir de várias fontes, além de ter que ler de vários lugares físicos, complica a otimização do banco dados, tem mais coisas para carregar na memória, sobrecarrega o cache, aumenta o uso de estruturas internas para construção do conjunto desejado, tem mais deslocamento do disco (isso é muito melhorado com SSD e mais ainda quando tem RAM para manter o DB todo ali, e logo terá a NVRAM), dificulta o aproveitamento de índices e redefinição da *query* para ter a melhor execução possível.

## Juntar dados X `JOIN`

O `JOIN` é basicamente um açúcar sintático, então não é o `JOIN` que é ruim, é a sua necessidade. Fazer manualmente a mesma coisa que um `JOIN` bem feito faz, dá na mesma (ou deveria). Veja:

```
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id

SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.a_id
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/JoinXWhere.sql).

Alguns SGDBs podem otimizar melhor o primeiro.

Se juntasse tudo da tabela `a` e `b` em uma coisa só, a performance de leitura seria melhor. Mas provavelmente pioraria bem a de escrita, provocaria inconsistências, a não ser que faça um mecanismo complexo. Poderia piorar a leitura em outro cenário. NoSQL tipicamente opta por isso.

Claro que em alguns casos fazer manualmente pode ficar mais óbvio alguma coisa que ajude otimizar mais, mas aí é aquela coisa, o mecanismo não é o culpado, é o desenvolvedor.

Se fizer vários `SELECT`s pode ser até pior dependendo do que fizer. Então em contraponto a não usar o `JOIN` em tabelas normalizadas, o `JOIN` costuma ser ótimo, porque geralmente é igual ou melhor. Você está juntando dados do mesmo jeito. E pode ser que o seu RMDBS não consiga fazer algumas otimizações porque não sabe que a intenção é fazer uma junção.

O problema da frase "`JOIN` deixa o banco de dados lento" é que ela é dita como boa prática, as pessoas não explicam o porquê, e quem consume a frase passa ter preconceito com a palavra-chave e não olham para o que realmente causa problema.

Dito tudo isto, é raro o `JOIN`, manual ou automático, bem feito, ser um real problema. Nem mesmo a normalização causa esse problema todo, embora tenha um custo real.

Se vai manter a normalização, e **acho** que deveria manter, não tema o `JOIN`, apenas use-o da forma correta, otimize as tabelas para trabalhar bem com eles. Veja se índices de cobertura podem ajudar, veja se possui índices que ajudam a otimização funcionar. Veja se tem alguma configuração ou forma de usar que faça o `JOIN` funcionar melhor.

> Me disseram que se fizer da maneira de criar uma página ASP e utilizando vários SELECTs dava para "colocar a mão no fogo" que aquele resultado era consistente. Do contrário a usar uma só query com 3 até 4 `JOINS`.

Não sei o que isto quer dizer, mas pode ser o que eu disse nos parágrafos anteriores.

## Chaves estrangeiras

O uso de FK costuma ser superestimado mesmo. Na verdade se usado errado causa tragédias na performance. Ela pode ser um dos responsáveis pelo `JOIN` (original, automático) ser muito lento, afinal pra atender a restrição que ela impõe pode acabar consultando muito mais informação que a necessária. Ele não sabe se precisa ir em toda cadeia de informação. Claro que pode obter maior consistência se usar chaves estrangeiras.

Algumas pessoas *optam* por [*views*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/101) para abstrair o acesso às tabelas físicas, assim criando um modelo lógico que evite você ter que lidar com os tais dos `JOIN`s. Nem sempre isso é uma boa ideia, abstrações podem esconder coisas importantes e te levar a cometer erros por isso.

## Performance e consistência

Quanto mais tabelas envolvidas, mais pode prejudicar a performance, até mesmo de forma exponencial. Quanto mais tabelas, mais combinações possíveis, mais dados são gerados, mais fontes a serem consultadas, menos oportunidades de otimizações, ou pelo menos mais complicado otimizar.

O que traz resultados inconsistentes é o uso errado. Não tem como o mecanismo fazer isso. Uma chave de fenda não aperta o parafuso erroneamente. Claro que ela terá dificuldades em colocar um prego na parede.

E não normalizar costuma dar muito mais resultados inconsistentes, e pior, que a programação não pode dar jeito, vai tudo sendo cadastrado errado.

Hoje está na moda falar em [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101), ainda que querem mesmo é falar em NoRel. Evita-se o `JOIN`, mas tem muita consulta que fica trágica, e... inconsistente, por definição. Na verdade o nome correto desse tipo de tecnologia devia ser NoConsistency porque é isso que realmente não tem. Cada vez mais elas estão usando relações e até SQL porque eram erradas.

Hoje todos os principais SGDBs permitem criar um modelagem híbrida que faz mais ou menos [o que o NoSQL faz sem as desvantagens dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101).

## O que fazer

Eu recomendo começar entender todo o funcionamento do banco de dados, fazer testes, não acreditar em respostas absolutas, ou seja, fazer diferente do que quase todo mundo faz, que é acreditar cegamente na opinião dos outros que não conhecem seu problema ou que não entendem do que estão falando. Só você pode achar solução para seu problema. Mas assim como as pessoas que trabalham como você ou que parecem não querer se aprofundar, você só poderá saber o certo estudando a fundo, sem pular etapas, sem se valer de resumos superficiais. Essa atitude está em falta em quase todo mercado de TI.

Comment: Eu tinha escrito uma reposta longa sobre isso, mas era meio grosseiro e eu fiquei com vergonha do meu post depois de ler o seu :\

Comment: @Renan ainda não terminei, preciso por mais algumas coisa,s mas como ando sem tempo, postei o que deu. Gosto das suas respostas, inclusive pelas "grosserias" que eu vivo fazendo :D Eu acho que o choque pode produzir resultados em quem está aberto a mudar o pensamento. Claro que não muda, e até afugenta quem quer ver só o que deseja. Depois eu leio a sua, mas sei que está tecnicamente perfeita, não acho que deveria apagar, mesmo antes de ver.

Comment: @Renan melhorei, aproveitei alguma coisa da sua que tá boa. Talvez vc queira recuperar editando alguma coisa que acha que ficou exagerada e fugiu demais do foco.

Comment: Eu acho que você já cobriu tudo, +1.

Comment: @bigown me perdoe pela demora de deixar um comentário a sua resposta. Ela está excelente e abriu mais ainda minha visão sobre os assuntos de banco de dados. Os bancos que estou manipulando não possuem normalizações, especificação do tipo de dados (é a maioria varchar, nada de date, int, smallint e etc), não ligam tabelas umas as outras e etc. Estou sempre sugerindo para que nos sistemas grandes que lá onde eu trabalho eles possam começar a melhorar a estrutura, pois certos trabalhos lá dentro estão bem complexos por conta da falta do bom uso dos recursos de um SGBD

Comment: Se o banco de dados não tem normalização não precisa de `JOIN`, mas se isto é verdade você tem um enorme problema na mão. Pra falar a verdade, acho pouco provável que não tenha normalização. Pode não ter todas as possíveis. É possível, mas é improvável. DB baseado em *string*? Acho que o `JOIN` é o menor dos seus problemas.

Comment: Realmente várias tabelas não estão normalizadas. Algumas  "estão" (pelo menos até a segunda forma) e outras não. Creio que sejam esses alguns dos motivos dos resultados inconsistentes que os joins estão trazendo.

Answer (score 5):

JOINs não são ruins exceto no caso da consulta gerar um produto (que é combinação de todas as linhas de uma tabela com o conjunto de resultados ou outra tabela).

Para resolver o problema de desempenho a primeira etapa é ver o plano de execução da consulta isso aponta onde estão os gargalos. As soluções mais simples são a criação de indices para colunas usadas em clásulas `join`, `where` `order by` (não é uma regra mas um ponto de partida), particionamento e até a reescrita.

Answer (score 3):

Você deveria verificar se o banco de dados tem índices.

A questão das FKs é um problema, mas para a consistência dos dados. E evitar assim registros órfãos.
Pode ser controlado isso via aplicação, claro que pode, mas qualquer bug pode vazar o problema.

Eu acho que os seus colegas deveriam verificar isso. E fazer algumas melhorarias para garantir uma base de dados mais consistente, e prevenir alguns problemas.

Os Joins são ótimos, não tem porque não utilizar. Mas os índices ajudam muito.

Criação de Views também pode facilitar.