# Chave primária e index no SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela onde a *Primary Key* `user_id` é usada como parâmetro de consulta, preciso definir este campo como índice para melhorar performance na consulta? Ou somente como *Primary key* é suficiente para tal?

Comment: Primary Key já é por default um índice. Mas por via das dúvidas, qual é seu SGBD?

Comment: Normalmente chave primária já é criada como índice, pois pesquisa por ela é algo muito rotineiro no banco. Você acha que sua performance está ruim? Qual SGDB você está usando?

Comment: Também relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216855/64969 ; veja o primeiro comentário da pergunta

Comment: Li os posts.. valeu.. Estou carregando o banco de dados para o servidor e começar a executar os testes, quando me deparei com a configuração.. Campo que é Primary key e definido como índice. Vou apagar a definição de índice e monitorar durante os testes.

Comment: Mas é MySQL que está utilizando?

Comment: O Oracle por exemplo não permite dois índices iguais na mesma tabela.

Comment: Não, você não precisa. Se já definiu essa coluna como uma primary key está especificando que é uma coluna aonde os registro não se repetem e portanto ela deve ser utilizada em suas querys para filtrar dados. No entanto se houver outra tabela qualquer no sistema, aonde exista um relacionamento com a tabela user, nessa outra tabela deve existir a chave primaria da tabela user que como definiu é: user_id e esse campo sim deve ser definido como um índice desta tabela.

Comment: @Everson Estou usando MySQL... Removi alguns algumas chaves que já são Primary key.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão o campo da tabela filha se chama foreign key e não index.

Comment: @Everson, LEIA ATENTAMENTE : "nessa outra tabela deve existir a chave primaria da tabela USER que como definiu é: user_id" ou seja ela será uma FK. Em portugês claro: CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA !