# Gostaria de entender o que é OLTP

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, terminologia

Me fizeram essa pergunta: O que é OLTP? Corri pra casa, abri o google e comecei a "goolgar", então me deparei com esses códigos, que dizem ter problemas em ambientes OLTP e não estou entendendo bulhufas:

```
public JsonResult ListarAlocacoes(AlocacaoView alocacaoView)
{
    var contratosAlocacaoList = ObterContratosAlocacao(alocacaoView);

    /* ... */
}

private IList<AlocacaoJson> ObterContratosAlocacao(AlocacaoView alocacaoView = null)
{
    var contratoList = BaseContext.DbContext.Set<Contrato>().Include("ContratoValores").ToList();

    foreach (var contrato in contratoList.Where( /* ... */ ))
    {
        var alocacao = MontarAlocacao(contrato, alocacaoView.CompetenciaId);

        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
}

private AlocacaoJson MontarAlocacao(Contrato contrato, DateTime dataCompetencia, int? equipeId = null)
{
    var alocacao = new AlocacaoJson();

    /* ... */

    alocacao.Equipe = ObterEquipeContrato(contrato, equipeId);
    alocacao.CustoTotal = ObterCustoTotalContrato(contrato, dataCompetencia);

    /* ... */
}

private EquipeJson ObterEquipeContrato(Contrato contrato, int? equipeId)
{
    var equipe = BaseContext.DbContext.Set<Equipe>().Find(equipeId.Value);

    /* ... */
}

private CustoTotalJson ObterCustoTotalContrato(Contrato contrato, DateTime dataCompetencia)
{
    var competencia = BaseContext.DbContext.Set<Competencia>().Where(c => c.Data == dataCompetencia).First(); ;
    var alocacao = BaseContext.DbContext.Set<Alocacao>().Include("AlocacoesProjeto").Include("Contrato").Include("Equipe").SingleOrDefault(c => c.CompetenciaData == competencia.Data);

    var valorHora = BaseContext.DbContext.Set<Funcao>().Find( /* ... */ ).ValoresHoras.SingleOrDefault( /* ... */ );

    var custoTotal = (decimal)(valorHora.Valor * alocacao.QtdeHoras) /* ... */;

    /* ... */
}
```

Num ambiente de produção isso daria pau numa abordagem OLTP? Por que?

Comment: Já deve ter visto, mais deixo de referência: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6934.oltp-x-olap-pt-br.aspx

Comment: O temo OLTP é mais associado a design de banco de dados, as principais caracteristicas dos sistemas (a maioria) que adotam essa abordagem são a normalização tabelas/entidades e a orientação a transações. Outro modelo é o OLAP usado em dataware houses seu foco é na leitura de dados por isso é menos normalizado que o OLTP.

Comment: Se entendi corretamente, se no banco de dados não forem utilizadas transações, o código acima pode produzir resultados inconsistentes.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 6):

Existem basicamente dois modelos de acesso/processamento de dados em banco de dados, o [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) (OnLine Transaction Processing) e o [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) (OnLine Analytical Processing).

OLTP é isso que quase todo mundo faz, cadastra, altera, muda algum ponto específico de um dado, remove, calcula, recupera para visualizar ou acessar de forma direta, faz algum processamento em lote para mudar os dados de forma geral. São os dados do dia.

OLAP é usado em análise de dados, em geral um grande volume e em conjunto. Os dados não costumam precisar ser os mais atuais, é comum pegar o que foi gerado no OLTP e copiado para trabalhar com o OLAP. É comum que no OLAP se gere novos dados baseados no que veio do OLTP. Pode vir de várias fontes, não necessariamente um banco de dados. Isto costuma chamar [Data Warehouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54007/101).

Qualquer código pode ter problemas em OLTP ou OLAP se não for bem feito. Só olhando o código não da para saber. Quem falou isso disse o porquê? Falou em que situação? Que volume de dados? Qual o nível de concorrência efetiva? Mostrou outros pontos relevantes do código e estrutura geral?

Se não tem nada disso a informação não é confiável. Lembre-se sempre que tem muita gente escrevendo coisas na internet, e a boa parte delas estão erradas, incompletas, imprecisas ou são tendenciosas.

Pode ser que seja a falta de transação correta, mas não sei, quando tem muita abstração se torna mais complicado afirmar. É possível, mas será que precisa dessa transação? É possível.

Inclusive há vários mitos sobre o assunto em artigos que até parecem confiáveis. Mas isso é outro assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).