# Qual a diferença conceitual de OLAP e OLTP?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

Boa tarde, pessoal, tudo bem?

Qual a diferença conceitual entre OLTP e OLAP?

*Contextualizando:*

> Estou começando meus estudos em data analysis e estou com uma dúvida que não consegui esclarecer mesmo após vários videos no youtube e pesquisas...
> O que eu tenho de conhecimento até agora:
> **OLTP** é voltado para **transações**, onde costuma-se adicionar ou deletar registros frequentemente, como em um estoque, conta corrente, fluxo de caixa, etc.
> **OLAP** é voltado para **análise de dados históricos**, comparar dimensões, etc, como por exemplo a quantidade de produtos vendidos por mês ou a evolução do saldo bancário de um indivíduo ao longo do tempo.

Mas tem algumas coisas que não consegui compreender ainda:

**1. OLTP e OLAP são ferramentas que integram com um banco de dados???** Por exemplo, ERP para OLTP e Tableau para o OLAP? Ambos interagem com um banco de dados mas um insere e deleta registros enquanto o outro obtem os registros e apenas analisa?

**2. Ou OLTP e OLAP são arquiteturas de um banco de dados?** Enquanto um é organizado extremamente normalizado e o outro... (nem sei qual seria esse tipo de arquitetura do OLAP)

**3.** Caso sejam ferramentas que interagem com o banco de dados, **é possível ambos serem utilizados no mesmo SGBD?** Por exemplo, os estudos que fiz até agora envolvem o SGBD MySQL, onde aprendi SQL, pelo que eu entendi, a partir da normalização se tem um resultado aproximado com OLTP. E para o OLAP? Posso utilizá-lo da mesma forma que o OLTP? Ou é necessário outro tipo de organização dos dados, outro BD, etc?

Não sou da área de TI, estou começando a aprender sobre banco de dados, softwares de BI e linguagens (python) nesses últimos tempos, portanto ainda não conheço os termos corretos e posso não me expressar muito bem, mas espero que eu tenha sido claro nas minhas dúvidas,

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Acho que isso responde: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281576/101 Também útil:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22120/101

Comment: Maniero, sim, respondeu 90%, só ainda me restou uma dúvida que não consegui compreender: Não existe diferença de SGBD então para cada aplicação? - Como sua resposta traz a solução, caso queira modifique para uma resposta, assim posso marcar como solução.

Comment: Não, é o jeito de trabalhar, é o tipo de operação que faz, não importa onde faz. Se responde, é melhor marcar como duplicata, ok?

Comment: Ok! Obrigado Maniero!! Pode marca-la como duplicata