# Quando devemos ter um banco de dados só para relatórios?

Tags: banco-de-dados, otimização, relatório

Em muitos casos usamos um banco de dados para fazer todas as operações necessários com esses dados. Há quem separe as operações e joga dados para outro banco de dados que fica responsável só pela geração dos relatórios.

Quando isso se torna pertinente e não é *overengineering*? Que perguntas preciso me fazer para tomar essa decisão de forma um pouco mais adequada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato, isso deve ser evitado. Alguns fatores podem liberar para fazer, ou até indicar a necessidade de fazer [OLAP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281576/101). Faça as perguntas:

- É fácil [desnormalizar as tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101)?
- Haverá ganhos significativos de produtividade dos programadores e/ou DBAs com os dados desnormalizados?
- Não é problema ter dados defasados ao que está acontecendo em tempo real?
- O banco atual está sobrecarregado e fazer o OLAP tornará o OLTP mais folgado?
- Uma atividade está atrapalhando as otimizações da outra mais importante por estar junto?
- A alimentação do OLAP não prejudicará o OLTP?
- Os relatórios [dependem de outros dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54007/101) que não estão no DB principal?
- Você usa ferramentas de *report* que não funcionam bem com o fornecedor de *database* do principal?

A carga provavelmente é o principal, não importa se é de espaço ocupado na memória de massa ou principal, ou de consumo de processador. Um exemplo de desperdício do principal quando precisa de muitas tabelas auxiliares para gerar os relatórios. Se vai fazer isso então pode ser melhor fazer separado.